# Problem reposting data periodically using AJAX to Laravel backend

Tags: php, ajax, settimeout

Am working on a PHP Laravel project whereby when a user clicks on a button on the website I perform some background task using AJAX to a PHP backend whreby I trigger a call to a payment gateway, when the user pays via his/her phone,,, I check the payment status (where 1 means paid, 0 means not paid) and if status is equal to 1, I redirect the user to a success page.

Currently am using AJAX to post data from the frontend to the backend and I want to post the data periodically after 5 seconds (where I give the user some time to pay before reaching out to the API to see if the status has changed to 1 then redirect the user).

Am trying to use setTimeout method in JavaScript and dd() the data from the controller which only dumps the data once but doesnt dump after 5 seconds

**AJAX code to post data to the backend after 5 seconds**

```
  $('.mpesa').on('click', function () {
      // run the first time; all subsequent calls will take care of themselves
      setTimeout(executeQuery, 5000);
    });

    function executeQuery() {
      alert('clicked');
        //Adds Class to the page when it loads
        $('.PAY').addClass("loading");
        //Gets the MPESA type
        var type = $('.mpesa').prop('id');
        var quote = $('#quote').val();
        var phone = $('#phone').val();
        //Converts to a JSON object
        var type ={
          'type': type,
          'quote' : quote,
          'phone' : phone,
        };

        console.log(type);

        $.ajax({
            //Contains controller of payment
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'paymentFinal',
            data: JSON.stringify(type),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function success(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function error(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
    //End AJAX call
```

**Controller file being called**

```
 public
    function payFinal(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());

    }
```

**Updated AJAX code**

```
$('.mpesa').on('click', function () {
    setInterval(function() {
       alert('clicked');
      //Gets the MPESA type
       var type = $('.mpesa').prop('id');
      var quote = $('#quote').val();
      var phone = $('#phone').val();
      //Converts to a JSON object
      var type ={
        'type': type,
        'quote' : quote,
        'phone' : phone,
      };

    console.log(type);
    $.ajax({
        //Contains controller of payment
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'paymentFinal',
        data: JSON.stringify(type),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function success(response) {
          if(response) {
              window.location.href="success";
          }
        },
        error: function error(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}, 15000); // Execute every 15 seconds
});
```

Comment: Can you attach a printscreen of the network and console tab of the browser's developer's tool ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` only executes the specified function once after the delay you set. Use `setInterval` instead so your function get called periodically.

=========================================================================

Update:
You want your function to execute immediately when the user clicks and after that calls itself every 15 secs. To achieve that, you can just use the following code:

```
$('.mpesa').on('click', executeQuery);

function executeQuery() {
  alert('clicked');
    //Adds Class to the page when it loads
    $('.PAY').addClass("loading");
    //Gets the MPESA type
    var type = $('.mpesa').prop('id');
    var quote = $('#quote').val();
    var phone = $('#phone').val();
    //Converts to a JSON object
    var type ={
      'type': type,
      'quote' : quote,
      'phone' : phone,
    };

    console.log(type);

    $.ajax({
        //Contains controller of payment
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'paymentFinal',
        data: JSON.stringify(type),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function success(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function error(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

    //use setTimeout here
    setTimeout(executeQuery, 15000);

}
```

Use `setTimeout` in your function to call itself would solve your problem.

=========================================================================

[To answer OP's question on how to stop the timer]

In your function, say you want the function to stop execution after 5 times.

Set up a variable outside of the function:

```
var counter = 0;
```

Then in `executeQuery`:

```
if (counter <= 5) { //or use your own logic
    counter++;
    setTimeout(executeQuery, 15000);
}
```

Remember that `setTimeout` is a one-time-thing, so you can just control when to stop calling it.

Comment: Sure thanks I have implemented setInterval please check the updated question,, the issue is that it is waiting for 15 seconds on the first click of the button but I want to wait for 15 seconds on subsequent calls but the first click should call the AJAX request without waiting for 15 seconds..

Comment: @Patweb So what you are expecting is that when the user first clicks the button, the function gets executed immediately, then the function will periodically run every 15 seconds since then, is that correct?

Comment: ,, Exacly thats what I want,, please check I have updated how I implement setInterval method

Comment: @Patweb check my updates. use `setTimeout` in your function to call itself.

Comment: ,, Your code works well but it works on infinite number of times,, what if I want to abort setTimeout after the 5th time..

Comment: @Patweb That's easy when you are using `setTimeout`. You can just add some extra logic to test if we should continue calling `setTimeout`. Wrap `setTimeout` in your conditional statement.

Comment: cant get you,, what I need is to abort the AJAX calls after the 5th time..this is because the code is looping infinitely,, I need to add a stopper.

Comment: @Patweb Okay since comment has words limit, I'll update my answer to show you how to break out of the "loop".

Comment: ,, Thanks alot it now works fine,, am a beginner in JS